# recurring billing /w cvv2

Tags: authorize.net, recurring-billing

I'm implementing a payment system and I'm not sure how to deal with cvv2 codes.  Our service offers a two week free trial.  We require the user to enter in billing information and we auth their card for $1. Two weeks later we do a separate auth & capture (we can't do a prior_auth_capture because the user can upgrade their plan during their trial).  We bill them each month from then on.

How am I supposed to use the cvv2 code in our situation?  We're not supposed to store the cvv2 code, so I can only use it with the auth that we initially do.  Is it worthing doing this just on the auth still?  I don't want the first auth to succeed (because it has the cvv2) and then prior auth + captures to fail because we don't keep it around.

Long story short I'm new at this company and I'm trying to fix their billing problems.  International customers in particular are getting payments declined (some, not all).  The current system doesn't pass along the name on the card to auth.net nor does it do any sort of address verification, which I suspect is what's giving international customers trouble.

I would think using cvv2 (if it'll work in our situation) and sending the actual name on the card should remedy the issue for international customers.  If not then address verification would be the next thing to try?  Does this make sense?  Sorry if my thoughts are a bit scattered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending the name on the card is useless as it not received nor used by the card processing companies. Also, AVS won't give anyone trouble except for the company who pays the credit card processing bills as their fees will be much higher for not doing it.

With Authorize.Net you should be using their ARB system for recurring payments. Once the subscription is established you don't have to do anything until the subscription runs out or is cancelled. This includes handling CVV and AVS issues. If you choose to use their AIM API for each and every payment then you'll have issues as you'll need to capture the CVV number for every transaction if you wish to perform CVV on those transactions. Of course, CVV is not required to process a transaction, so if you don't submit it the transaction will still go through anyway.

If international card holders are having issues it's more likely because the card is international and higher risk then then AVS or CVV issues. Those two tools are for fraud detection on your end. Not card approval by the processors.

Comment: +1 - almost nobody, even those that design these systems, understands that CVV and AVS isn't required to get a transaction approved and almost never is related to declines.